# SqLite - Query with two tables

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. The first table is **photos** and it has the fields:

```
id, stationId, walkId, imageName
```

The second table is **stations** and its fields:

```
stationId, name, walkId, description, turn
```

I want to get the field `imageName` from table **photos** and I want these records to be ordered by field `turn` from table **stations**.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [inner join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm):

```
SELECT imageName 
FROM photos INNER JOIN stations ON photos.stationId = stations.id 
ORDER BY turn ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f74bbf/9)

Comment: Thank you so much! Also in my query I have a where clause. I have put the where clause after inner join and before order. Does it true, doesn't?

Comment: That is the correct order, the diagrams on [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), while a little difficult to read, will give you an idea of the structure of a SELECT statement.